# span:hover won't work in Firefox

Tags: css, hover, opacity, transition, html

I don't know why but :hover won't work in Firefox on my code.. It's working perfect in Chrome and Safari, even in IE is doing well.

I've tried with .over as well, but nothing changed.

html code:

```
<div id="proekti">
        <article id="red1" class="sliki">
            <span>
                <div class="text">
                <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </span>
            <div></div>

            <span>
                <div class="text">
                <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </span>
           <div></div>

            <span>
                <div class="text">
                <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </span>
            <div></div>

            <span>
                <div class="text">
                <h3></h3>
                </div>
            </span>
            <div></div>
        </article>
</div>
```

css code:

```
#proekti .sliki > div {
    width:25%;
    display:inline;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
}

article.sliki > span {
    width:25%;
    height:100%;
    display:inline-block;
    position:absolute;
    border:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    background: rgba(55,55,55,0.6);
    color:#FFF;
    opacity:0;
    z-index:1000;
}

article.sliki > span:hover {
    transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all 1s ease-out;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong. SPAN is an INLINE element, but you placed DIV (block element) inside it. It's not valid. You can use ONLY inline elements inside another inline elements.

This is not good solution, but :hover will work for you if you add {display:block;} property to span (article.sliki > span).

Comment: hello Pavlo thank you for your comment.. I've tried with span instead of div even I deleted everything inside the article > span but still nothing, :hover was working only on chrome, safari & ie.